# traverse listnode in python

Tags: python, loops, linked-list, traversal

Can someone help me with how can I traverse through below given listnode in python. I have written this command and am getting such outputs.

```
list1=[1,2,4]
```

Command:-

```
print(list1)
print(list1.val)
print(list1.next.val)
```

OUTPUT:-

```
ListNode{val: 1, next: ListNode{val: 2, next: ListNode{val: 4, next: None}}}
1
2
```

Comment: list1 is just a list so you traverse it by index. I think you're getting confused with singly linked lists

Comment: Are you by chance working on a code challenge site? They may do the conversion from list to linked list behind the scenes. It is not really clear what you are asking here. How does `list1=[1,2,4]` relate to the "command" section?

Comment: Why no reaction to my comment?

Comment: Yes, I am working on a code challenge site. I wasn't asking for that actually. Anyways I got my answer Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the output you have listed at the end of your question, you would need to create a linked list. For instance, if you define the following class:

```
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, val, nxt=None):
        self.val = val
        self.next = nxt

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"ListNode{{val: {self.val}, next: {self.next}}}"
```

And if you then define `list1` as follows:

```
list1 = ListNode(1, ListNode(2, ListNode(4, None)))
```

Then the "commands" will give the output that you listed.

### List to Linked List

If you want to create the above linked list from the list [1,2,4], then use this function:

```
def createLinkedList(values):
    head = None
    for val in reversed(values):
        head = ListNode(val, head)
    return head
```

Now you can convert a plain list to a linked list as follows:

```
list1 = createLinkedList([1,2,4])
```

### Linked List to list

If you want to do the opposite, and create a standard list from a linked list, then define this function:

```
def linkedListIterator(head):
    while head:
        yield head.val
        head = head.next
```

Now, if you have a linked list, you can pass it to the above function. For instance:

```
list1 = createLinkedList([1,2,4])
lst = list(linkedListIterator(list1))
```

`lst` will be [1,2,4]

Comment: a singly linked list is already given. I need to traverse through it and print the values in the list. can you help me out with that?

Comment: In your question you have not a given linked list. You have a plain list [1,2,4]. This is the part that is not clear in your question. I have added a section to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, it appears as though you are confusing a `list` with a `singly linked list`.

With the list provided you would just iterate with a `for loop` like this:

```py
list1=[1,2,4]


for L in list1:
    print(L)
```

Which gives the output:

```
1
2
4
```

For linked lists, please refer to this:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python_data_structure/python_linked_lists.htm

Comment: This isn't a simple list. It is a singly linked list. Can you tell me how to traverse through the singly linked list?

Comment: The `list` that is stated in the question is just a standard `list` in python and is one of the core data types (see here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html). A `singly-linked-list` is different to this and the link in the answer points to its usage.